# Cannot Sort prices from low to high and cannot get max and min prices from below code in java

Tags: java, selenium

driver.get("https://www.amazon.in/gp/bestsellers/?ref_=nav_cs_bestsellers");
List v= new ArrayList();

List  c=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("span[class='a-size-base a-color-price']"));

```
    for(int i=0;i<c.size();i++)
    {
   
        String j= c.get(i).getText().replaceAll("[₹,]", "");
        v.add(j);
    }
    Collections.sort(v, Comparator.comparingDouble(Double::parseDouble));
       System.out.println(v);
      
}
```

}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
at java.base/java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:735)
at java.base/java.util.Comparator.lambda$comparingDouble$8dcf42ea$1(Comparator.java:536)
at java.base/java.util.TimSort.binarySort(TimSort.java:296)
at java.base/java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:221)
at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1307)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1721)
at java.base/java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:179)
at sortingg.main(sortingg.java:29)

Should get sorted prices and min and max prices. Cannot Sort prices from low to high and cannot get max and min prices from below code in java

Comment: what is being printed?

Comment: [, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 1000.00, 1060.00, 1495.00, 1799.00, 1799.00, 1999.00, 225.00, 2799.00, 330.00, 396.00, 479.00, 500.00, 719.00, 739.00, 747.00, 797.00, 995.00, 995.00] This is getting printed

Comment: @DarshanKadam, These are properly sorted String`s. You obviously want to sort numbers, not strings.

Comment: Yes actually want to sort these numbers in ascending

Comment: Your call to `Collections.sort(v);` will sort the Strings according to the logic in `String.compare`, not by number

Comment: Understood, so they are sorting only the first letter of each result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your code is sorting strings, not numbers. And he does the job exactly right.

Depending on whether you want to convert your strings to numbers and work as numbers, or you want to leave strings as they are, you can use code like this:

```
// if you want output as Doubles
v.stream()
   .map(Double::parseDouble)
   .sorted()
   .forEach(System.out::println);

// or if you want Strings
v.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(Double::parseDouble))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

or without using StreamAPI:

```
// sort List<String> by it's Double values
Collections.sort(v, Comparator.comparingDouble(Double::parseDouble));
```

You will still get an error because there are empty strings in your list that can not be converted to numbers. There is no way to convert `""` to any number. Thus, you need to take care that your list does not contain empty strings, as well as `null` values.

One way to do this:

```
String j = c.get(i).getText().replaceAll("[₹,]", "");
if (!j.isEmpty) {
    v.add(j);
}
```

Comment: Can you do this with Arraylist please?

Comment: double j= Double.parseDouble(c.get(i).getText().replaceAll("[₹,]", ""));
   v.add(j); will this work from my code ?

Comment: @DarshanKadam, You need to completely exclude empty lines from your List, because `Double.parseDouble("")` will throw's `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: {String j= c.get(i).getText().replaceAll("[₹,]", "");
   v.add(j);
  }
  Collections.sort(v, Comparator.comparingDouble(Double::parseDouble));
     System.out.println(v);
    }

}  Tried this but getting error

Comment: @DarshanKadam, `if (!j.isEmpty()) v.add(j);`